# rails one to-many two sided relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wonder how to do the following in Rails in the right way.

I have class Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bids, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :user
end
```

and class Bid

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
end
```

The following works perfectly fine,

```
order = Order.find(1)
order.bids
```

However sometimes I want to get order by bid

```
order = bid.order
```

And of course backwards it doesn't work

In addition I want the following to be OK

```
bid.order.user.username
```

What the best way to do in Rails?

Comment: Is it a typo that you wrote `belong_to` in Order class? Btw what you wrote should work. when you say `bid.order`, what dou u receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order = bid.order` should work. Not sure why it happens.

```
bid.order.user.username
```

To call this,
 you can probably try

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :order
 has_one :user, :through => :order
end
```

and call

> bid.user.username